# Groovy MetaClass (related) memory leak with Java 7 parallel class loader

Tags: java, groovy, memory-leaks, classloader, java-7

### Problem background

I run a Groovy/Grails system that dynamically compiles and loads user-defined code. This is basically done via `GroovyClassLoader`.

I'm seeing the dynamic classes themselves both loaded AND unloaded just fine. I have added the

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

flags and that works fine. The dynamic classes are being unloaded when the classloader is GC'ed.

### Problem description

However my heap memory is leaking, and this is the source of the leak:

[image: jvisualvm screenshot]

Now, the `Launcher$AppClassLoader` has a property `parallelLockMap` defined in `java.lang.ClassLoader`. Apparently this `ConcurrentHashMap` is used to hold parallel class loading locks in Java 7. Check out the [source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180526073028/http://grepcode.com:80/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/ClassLoader.java/).

The entries held in this map have `String` keys (the class name for which the lock applies) and `Object` values (the lock objects). There are two kinds of leaking keys:

```
"groovy.runtime.metaclass.MyDynamicallyLoadedClassNameMetaClass"
"MyDynamicallyLoadedClassNameBeanInfo"
```

So to me it looks like these keys are created in `parallelLockMap` when the `*MetaClass` and `*BeanInfo` classes are loaded, but they are not removed when the associated dynamically loaded class (and its metaclasses) are unloaded. Now this is getting quite deep into the internals of Groovy and its metaclass system, and I'm running out of expertise.

### Test Case

This will eventually run you out of heap space, although it will take a while:

```
    String newClass = "class CLASSNAME {}"
    while (true) {
        GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
        Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(newClass.replace("CLASSNAME", "NewClass"+System.nanoTime()))
        clazz.newInstance()
    }
```

Be sure to run this with the above JVM flags so that you run out of **heap space**, not **PermGen** space. Again, PermGen gets garbage collected nicely, no leak there.

[image: See where this leads?]

### Questions

1) Is this a bug in Groovy or Java 7? Whose responsibility would it be to clean the `parallelLockMap`? Should I submit an issue report?

2) Is there a workaround? I'm thinking of using a custom `ClassLoader` that does not first try to delegate class loading to its parent for these `MetaClass` and `BeanInfo` classes, thus preventing the call to `java.lang.ClassLoader#loadClass(..)`. I'm not an expert in Java/Groovy classloading, though.

EDIT: I have submitted a Groovy JIRA [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507205446/https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6655).

EDIT: On the JDK side this issue has recently been reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037342?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel).

Comment: What version of Groovy out of interest?

Comment: @tim_yates, the version of Grails I'm currently using includes Groovy 2.0.5. I tried searching the JIRA for related issues, but couldn't find any. Do you think this might be fixed in a more recent version?

Comment: @tim_yates Added a general test case to the question, will test with a more recent Groovy version.

Comment: IntelliJ overrides this leaking behavior by using a weak string interner in its classloader: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/cd4238cf943dcd9ee6dee730ea006e4deb9e74a4

Comment: I have found a way of get it done https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8113?focusedCommentId=17279013&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17279013